# How to handle Format Exception in C#

Tags: c#, exception, formatexception

Hi I'm trying to make simple calculator as i'm new to C# and not familiar with, anyway when i try to handle format exception by try catch i didn't work when I enter a value rather than number it always throw an exception without executing the catch block

```
try
{
  Val1 = double.Parse(opr1.Text);
  Val2 = double.Parse(opr2.Text);
  double sum = Val1 + Val2;
  label1.Text = sum.ToString();
}
catch(Exception ex //or FormatException) 
{
  label1.Text = "Please enter the proper data type";
}
```

always gives an error when trying to convert the wrong value without executing the catch block

Comment: Are you running this within your IDE? Is the IDE itself showing a message box like 'Exception occurred' - if so simply press F5 or continue to continue code execution to enter your catch block (your IDE may be configured to break when an exception is thrown?).

Comment: Go to Debug -> Windows -> ExceptionSettings and look at Common Language Runtime Exceptions for the setting on FormatException, then follow the example given below by @mybirthname

Comment: I copy pasted your code to my visual studio and the try catch block DID catch a "Input string was not in a correct format." exception. Could you explain more what your problem is ?

Comment: `always gives an error`, then put the error in your question.

Comment: Solved, @TVOHM it is like you said thank you :) and to all of you guys

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to handle it without an exception.

```
bool noErrorMsg= true;

noErrorMsg &= double.TryParse(opr1.Text, out Val1);
noErrorMsg &= double.TryParse(opr2.Text, out Val2);

if(!noErrorMsg)
{
    //Error
}
```

`TryParse` will return false if the Parsing is not possible.

Comment: and what if he adds more fields ? like Val3,4,5,6,7,8 ?

Comment: I don't see any problem if the fields are more than 10.

Comment: @Stralos If he adds more fields he should switch to an array

Comment: Ok actually I tried something like this and it works fine but i want to use try catch method cause I'm actually learning Exception handling :)

Comment: @MohammedAhmedMohammed double.TryParse can throw 3 different exception in different cases, so in perfect scenario you should check for all 3 of them: ArgumentNullException, FormatException, OverflowException. It is bad practice to catch Exception.